# How right use $.each for json array?

Tags: jquery, each

*Good day.*

*first make json in php:*

```
$a=0;
foreach(...){
  $a++;
  $ArrImage["$a"] = $PathToThumbnailImage;
}

return json_encode($ArrImage);
```

*second  - jquery:*

```
       $("#form").ajaxForm({
            url:        './index.php?page=test',
            success:    function(data){
            var files = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(files);
            //files in console.log:
            // Object {1: "./DIR/90_1409499383.jpg", 
            //         2: "./DIR/90_1409499383.jpg"} 
            $.each(data.d, function(key, value) {
                console.log('test' + key + ":" + value)
            });

            //now we get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' 
            //                  of undefined `


            }
        }).submit();
```

*Tell me please why we get error and how right use `$.each`?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should replace your `data.d` with `files`
it requires a object or array to iterate
[from the Jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) :-

> $.each

:- `A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays`

Hence files is your Object not data.d

```
$("#form").ajaxForm({
            url:        './index.php?page=test',
            success:    function(data){
            var files = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(files);
            //files in console.log:
            // Object {1: "./DIR/90_1409499383.jpg", 
            //         2: "./DIR/90_1409499383.jpg"} 
            $.each(files, function(key, value) {
                console.log('test' + key + ":" + value)
            });



            }
        }).submit();
```

Comment: bcoz files is your parsed object

Answer (score 0):

When you create a request via Ajax it will use the data which is outputted.

When you use 'return' you aren't outputting anything.

You have to change 'return' to 'echo' or 'print' or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

This I try to correct

```
$("#form").ajaxForm({
    url : './index.php?page=test',
    //you miss this
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data){
        // your server return data not data.d
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            console.log('test' + key + ":" + value);
        });
    }
}).submit();
```

Comment: try to use echo nott return in your server and tell me what do u seen in conole.log after that

Answer (score 0):

You can use `header('Content-Type: application/json');` in your PHP script so you do not have  to use `JSON.parse` on the client-side.

```
$ArrImage = array();
foreach(...){
    $ArrImage[] = $PathToThumbnailImage;
}
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($ArrImage);
```

When you're not sure whether what is returned is JSON or not you can write:

```
success: function( data ) {
    data = $.type( data ) === 'string' ? JSON.parse( data ) : data;
    $.each(data, function( key, value ) {
    .......
    });
}
....
```